# Confused regarding Linear Invariant Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

Assuming a linear transformation $T : \mathrm{V \rightarrow V}$, let $\mathrm{W \subset V}$ so that $\mathrm{W} \ne \{0\}$. 
If $T(\mathrm{W}) \subseteq \mathrm{W}$ then $\mathrm{W}$ is $T$ invariant, and can be denoted $T|_W : \mathrm{W \rightarrow W}$ such that for $\forall w \in \mathrm{W},\quad T|_W(w) = T(w)$

I believe that I understand most of the definitions and implications associated with this term, however I seem to have a problem with the final equation. I'll elaborate:

let $\mathrm{V = \mathbb{R}_3[x]}$ and $\mathrm{B} = \{x^2, x+1, 1\}$ be a base of mentioned vector space such that:
$\mathrm{T}(x^2) = x^2\mathrm{,\quad} \quad\mathrm{T}(x+1) = x + 1\mathrm{,\quad} \quad\mathrm{T}(1) = 1$

$[T]_B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = I_3$

We can see that $\mathrm{W} = span\{x+1,1\}$ maintains the conditions and definitions above. The following also occurs:

$[T|_W]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = I_2$

I understand the equation $T|_W(w) = T(w)$ when the representation is over $\mathrm{\mathbb{R}_3[x]}$, specifically $\mathrm{\mathbb{R}_2[x]}$ in our case. However, how is it interpreted when we deal with matrix representation or coordinate vector representation, considering we identify them with one another when dealing with invariant sub-spaces, and their dimensions aren't equal.

Comment: $W$ cannot equal to $\{x+1,1\}$, because that set is not a *subspace*.  You are looking for linear invariant *subspaces*, not subsets.

Comment: $[T|_W]_B$ does not make sense because $B$ is a basis for $V$, not for $W$. To talk about the matrix representation of $T|_W$, you need to specify a basis for $W$, not a basis for $V$. In this particular case you have chosen a subset $B'$ of $B$ to span $W$, but this is not always possible.

Answer (score 3):

Your question (i.e. your final sentence) is not very clear, but if I understand it correctly, it can be answered with [block matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix):

Let $V$ be a linear space with base $B=(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ and for some $p\le n,$ let $W$ be the subspace spanned by $B'=(e_1,\dots,e_p).$

$W$ is $T$-invariant iff the matrix of $T$ in $B$  is of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}P&Q\\0&R\end{pmatrix}$$
where $P$ is a $p\times p$ matrix, which is then the matrix of $T_{|W}$ in $B'.$